# "Return type of main is not int" warning on macOS

Tags: c, warnings, return-value, program-entry-point, void

So I have a MacBook Pro 2017 and whenever I compile a program that as "void main", the compiler gives me a warning saying that the return type of main is not int...

```
void main(){

(...)

}
```

Comment: Change the return type of main to be int: `int main(){`

Comment: `main` is *supposed* to return `int` (in a hosted environment, anyway).  Yes, you will see countless examples of `void main()` on the web and in more than a few books (including some good ones) - those are all, strictly speaking, incorrect.  Using the wrong return type results in *undefined behavior*, and compilers are not *required* to issue a diagnostic for undefined behavior.  More of them are doing so now, though, since it's such a common error.

Answer (score 4):

Like the warning says, you should define the return type as an `int`:

```
int main() {
    // bunch of code...

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Current versions of the C standard require that the `main` function has a return type of `int`.  So you need to change the definition to `int main()` and have it return a value.

Section 5.1.2.2.1 of the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) detailing hosted environments states the following:

> *1* The function called at program startup is named `main`. The implementation declares no prototype for this function. **It shall be
>   defined with a return type of `int`** and with no parameters:
>
> ```
> int main(void) { /* ... */ }
> ```
>
> or with two parameters (referred to here as `argc` and `argv`, though any
>   names may be used, as they are local to the function in which they are
>   declared):
>
> ```
> int main(int argc, char *argv[]) { /* ... */ }
> ```
>
> or equivalent or in some other implementation-defined manner.

Note that a definition of `int main()` is allowable as the empty parameter list means the function takes no parameters.  From section 6.7.6.3:

> *14* An identifier list declares only the identifiers of the parameters of the function. **An empty list in a function declarator
>   that is part of a definition of that function specifies that the
>   function has no parameters.** The empty list in a function declarator
>   that is not part of a definition of that function specifies that no
>   information about the number or types of the parameters is supplied.

Specifying the main function as `void main()` is a pre-standardized variant from the K&R days and is no longer valid.

Comment: Maybe some comments about why `int main()` is a legal substitute for `int main(void)`?

Comment: @DavidBowling Done.

Comment: Hmmm. I was thinking of this: ["An empty list in a function declarator that is part of a definition of that function specifies that the function has no parameters."](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.6.3p14). Does this not apply here?

Comment: @DavidBowling Ah, correct.  I was thinking of declarations as opposed to definitions.  I'll update.

Answer (score 0):

It's expected that `main()` will return an `int` value. A minimal start is:

```
int main() {
  return 0;
}
```

A more formal version which accepts command-line parameters:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  return 0;
}
```

Declaring it with a different type makes it incompatible. Some older compilers may not care, but Xcode's does.

C has been around a long time and has evolved considerably from its early days. If you're using an older reference you may find examples with really strange notation, or conventions that are no longer value.